# Rails conditional validation through one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a conditional validation of a field. Such that it only validates if another field is a specific value. The problem here is, that this other field is a one to many relation, and I can't seem to get it working. 
Here is the relevant code:

```
class CreateInvolvedPartyTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :involved_party_types do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateInvolvedParties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :involved_parties do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.references :involved_party_type

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class InvolvedParty < ActiveRecord::Base
    def ipt_cd?
        self.involved_party_type.code == 'I'
    end

    validates :first_name, presence: { message: "Please insert first name" }
    validates :last_name, presence: { message: "Please insert last name" }, :if => :ipt_cd?
    validates :involved_party_type, presence: { message: "Please select involved party type" }

    belongs_to :involved_party_type
end
```

The above code fails with:

> undefined method `code' for nil:NilClass

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post the code where you create/validate the object in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `self.involved_party_type` in InvolvedParty#ipt_cd? is nil. You should test the presence of involved_party_type before calling #code on it, or use #try.

```
def ipt_cd?
  return false if involved_party.nil?
  involved_party_type.code == 'I'
end

def ipt_cd?
  self.involved_party_type.try(:code) == 'I'
end
```

Or you can avoid the problem by only invoking the validation if involved_party_type exists.

```
validates :last_name, presence: { message: "Please insert last name" }, if: -> { involved_party_type && ipt_cd? }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're getting confused with calling `instance` and `class` level data.

> - "Instance" data is populated each time a class is invoked
> - "Class" data is static, always appending to the class

The cosmetic difference between the two is that `class` data is typically called through *self* (EG `def self.method` & `self.attribute`), whilst `instance` data is called with "naked" attributes (IE without `self`).

You're calling the following:

```
def ipt_cd?
   self.involved_party_type.code == 'I'
end
```

The problem is that you're referencing `self` as if it's a piece of *class* data. What you want is the *instance* equivalent:

```
def ipt_cd?
   involved_party_type.code == 'I'
end
```

---

As the other answer states, your error is caused by a piece of data having no method for `code`, meaning it's nil.

The casue of this is here (solution is above -- IE remove `self`):

```
involved_party_type.code == 'I'
```

Thus, if you want to make sure you don't receive this error, you'll have to ensure that `involved_party_type` is present. This can be done by first ensuring you're referencing the *instance* variant of the data, followed by ensuring it's there anyway. The other answer provided the best way to achieve that.

---

Finally, I think your structure could be improved.

Referencing the actual data representation of an associated field is bad practice in my opinion. You're trying to *create* a new piece of data, and yet you're referencing an associated attribute?

Why not do the following:

```
#app/models/party_type.rb
class PartyType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :involved_parties
end

class InvolvedParty < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :party_type

   validates :first_name, :party_type, presence: true
   validates :last_name, presence: { message: "Please insert last name" }, if: :cd?

   private

   def cd?
      party_type == PartyType.find_by(code: "I").pluck(:id)
   end
end
```

This will send another DB query *but* it removes the dependency on specific data. Your current setup is not relying on foreign keys, but on a value which may change.

Whilst this recommendation also relies on data (IE `code` == `I`), it uses it as a quantifier within `ActiveRecord`. That is, you're not comparing the data, but the relationship.

Comment: I got this error: undefined method `pluck' for #<InvolvedPartyType:0x0000000bedda40>. The above answer worked perfectly. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Sorry if you received multiple notifications from my previous comments. I think removing `self` does nothing, since `self` in instance method refers to the instance. `PartyType.find_by(code: "I").pluck(:id)` does not work either, as find_by returns the first record that matches the condition as an ActiveRecord instance.